# How can i call MiddleName and Lastname from in else statement at the last part of my conditional statement?

Tags: c#

```
string FirstName, LastName;
char MiddleInitial;

Console.Write("Enter  first name: ");
FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

if (FirstName.Equals("null"))
{
    Console.Write("Insert middle initial ");
    Console.Write("\nInsert last name \n");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");
    MiddleInitial = Console.ReadLine()[0];
    Console.Write("Insert  last name: ");
    LastName = Console.ReadLine();
}

int Months = 1 ;

if (Months == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Incorret");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nYour record");
    Console.WriteLine("FIRST NAME:{0}", FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
    Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);
}
```

I can call the FirstName, but the MiddleInitial and LastName is not working if you run it in Visual studio. what is the possible error?

The program output should display like this:

```
Enter  first name: Joshua
Insert middle initial:F 
Insert  last name:Capili
  
Your record
FIRST NAME:Joshua
MIDDLE INITIAL: f
LASTNAME:Capili
```

this Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial); Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName); it says that "use of unassigned local variables 'MiddleInitial' "use of unassigned local variables 'LastName' that's why i can't run the program.

Comment: What do you mean by not working. Are you getting any errors. What is the current output you are getting. What is the error you are currently facing.  Place breakpoints and debug, You can find the error and in which line you are facing the error.

Comment: i'm facing error in this                                                                 
          Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
            Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);                                                                   it says that  "use of unassigned local variables 'MiddleInitial'    "use of unassigned local variables 'LastNamel'

Comment: have you ever tried it in your IDE?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, isn't it?  You aren't assigning those variables if `FirstName` is equal to the string `"null"` (which itself is weird, as that's only going to happen if the user types out "null")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm seeing is that the problem with your code is in the logic you are writing. The fact is that you ask for FirstName but as long at it's null your program won't run inside the else statement

```
Console.Write("Enter  first name: ");
    FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

    while (FirstName.Equals("null")){
        Console.Write("Enter  first name: ");
        FirstName = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    
     Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");
     MiddleInitial = Console.ReadLine()[0];

    while (MiddleInitial.Equals("null")){
        Console.Write("Insert middle initial: ");
        MiddleInitial = Console.ReadLine()[0];
    }

        Console.Write("Insert  last name: ");
        LastName = Console.ReadLine();

    while (LastName.Equals("null")){
        Console.Write("Insert  last name: ");
        LastName = Console.ReadLine();
    }

       
       

    int Months = 1 ;

    if (Months == 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorret");
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYour record");
        Console.WriteLine("FIRST NAME:{0}", FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("MIDDLE INITIAL: {0}", MiddleInitial);
        Console.WriteLine("LASTNAME: {0}", LastName);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Understanding error messages is a critical component of programming. Always make sure to review and comprehend the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165) of error messages whenever possible:

> Use of unassigned local variable 'name'
>
> The C# compiler doesn't allow the use of uninitialized variables. If
> the compiler detects the use of a variable that might not have been
> initialized, it generates compiler error CS0165. For more information,
> see Fields. This error is generated when the compiler encounters a
> construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even
> if your particular code does not. This avoids the necessity of overly
> complex rules for definite assignment.

In your case, you are using a variable (or rather two, `MiddleInitial` and `LastName`) without potentially being assigned, due to your conditional statements. The compiler will not allow this.

You can solve this by simply initializing them to white space.

```
string FirstName, LastName = "";
char MiddleInitial = ' ';
```

Comment: Thanks alot it really helped me to get this through. More power si David God bless.

Comment: you know i'm new here how can i give you a good feedback. I badly want y'all give 5 stars hahaha